# How to create the logical $|0_L\rangle$ state for the Steane's 7-qubit code?

Tags: quantum-state, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, error-correction

I don't know how to prepare using Qiskit the following state in order to implement a Steane's 7-qubit code circuit (I omit the normalization factor):
\begin{align*} |0_L\rangle =&|0000000\rangle+|1010101\rangle+|0110011\rangle+|1100110\rangle+
\\
+&|0001111\rangle+|1011010\rangle+|0111100\rangle+|1101001\rangle
\end{align*}
Furthermore, I was wondering if it exists a general procedure in order to prepare an arbitrary multipartite state like $|0_L\rangle$.

Comment: You have to use the initialize() function. Look at this post: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/how-to-create-an-arbitrary-state-in-qiskit-for-a-local-qasm-simulator

Comment: Thank you! What if I wanted to use only gates (even if it is not necessary since `initialize()` exists)? Is there a rule to prepare this kind of states (like for example the combo Hadamard on first qubit+ CNOT for Bell basis in bipartite case)?

Comment: I am not aware of a general rule. Specific states may have ultra-optimized circuits. The initialize() function is based on a nice algorithm (which is not very recent, and I would like to know if there are even better ones). Note: in your example the $|1011010\rangle$ state appears twice.

Comment: Thank you again, I've edited the question, now it should be correct.

Comment: Did you look at this question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13024/circuit-for-implementing-steanes-code-for-quantum-error-correction? It gives the theory, although not the specific qiskit implementation.

Comment: Yes, but I suspect that this is slightly different from what I want to do. Furthermore, I knew that stabilizers are involved in the creation of graph (and cluster, of course) states and I am not 100% sure that this is the case of the state I need to prepare. I began about a month ago to study these topics and I don't have enough experience yet in how to properly classificate states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a circuit that can create the desired state (similar ideas were discussed in this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13025/9459)), if all mentioned measurements yield $|0\rangle$ state:

[image]

or in a more compact [form](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22,1,%22X%22,1,%22X%22,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22,%22X%22,1,1,%22X%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22%5D%5D%7D) (the circuits are constructed via [quirk](https://algassert.com/quirk)). The first three qubits are ancillary qubits and the rest are the qubits where $|0_L\rangle$ will be created if after the measurements all ancillary qubits are in the $|000\rangle$ state, otherwise one should repeat the procedure until the desired measurement result will be archived.

---

Let's go step by step. The circuit has three parts and in each step, we assume that the measured state of the ancillary is $|0\rangle$. The normalization factors are omitted.

1. The state after measuring the first ancillary qubit in the $|0\rangle$ state: (measuring $XIXIXIX$ stabilizer)

$$|000\rangle \big( |0000000\rangle + |1010101\rangle \big)$$

2. The state after measuring the second ancillary qubit in the $|0\rangle$ state:
   (measuring $IXXIIXX$ stabilizer)

$$|000\rangle \big( |0000000\rangle + |1010101\rangle + 
|0110011\rangle + |1100110\rangle\big)$$

3. The state after measuring the third ancillary qubit in the $|0\rangle$ state:
   (measuring $IIIXXXX$ stabilizer)

$$|000\rangle |0_L\rangle = |000\rangle \big( |0000000\rangle + |1010101\rangle + 
|0110011\rangle + |1100110\rangle \\
|0001111\rangle + |1011010\rangle +|0111100\rangle + |1101001\rangle \big)$$

After disregarding the ancillary qubits that are in the $|000\rangle$ state we will have the desired $|0_L\rangle$ state. The probability that each measurement outcome will be $|0\rangle$ is $0.5$, thus the probability of creating the $|0_L\rangle$ state with this circuit is $0.125$. For Qiskit, one can implement the circuit mentioned above, then apply any algorithm or gate that is needed on the $|0_L\rangle$ state, and after the computation disregard all the results where ancillary qubits are not in the $|000\rangle$ state.

Comment: Very clear, but I don't understand the part about the probability of the outcome. I mean, on the three ancillary qubits you have two Hadamards thus, provided that $H\cdot H=I$, where $I$ is the identity, you should get $|0\rangle$  with probability 1, or am I missing something?

Comment: @HubOne, There is no place where we have $H \cdot H$, we always have control gates in the middle of Hadamards in this circuit. The probabilities can be seen from the link that I have shared for the equivalent circuit. Also, the probabilities can be obtained by calculating the state before, for example, the first measurement.

Comment: Of course, by simulating your circuit you're totally right, but I am still thinking I am missing something about the probabilistic part of your answer. I naively (and wrongly) think that, since the Hadamards are acting only on the control and the CNOT leaves unchanged the control, on that bit the CNOT acted like $I$ and thus we had $H\cdot H$. Can you show me why am I wrong?

Comment: @HubOne, let me try to explain with a simpler circuit. Can you find the state before the measurement of this two-qubit [circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit={%22cols%22:[[%22H%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[%22H%22],[%22Measure%22]]})? What is the probability of measuring $|0\rangle$ state? CNOT is a two qubit gate and it changes the state of both qubits. For example, if after CNOT we created an entangled state, that already means that the state of both qubits is changed (the control qubit's state inclusive...it will have some correlation with the target qubit).

Comment: In some cases, CNOT doesn't change the state of the control qubit, but it is not the general behavior of the CNOT gate.

Comment: Is the state before the measurement $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle |0\rangle + |-\rangle |1\rangle)$? However, I can see the problem now, it totally makes sense. Thank you

Comment: @HubOne, you're welcome :). You are right. One question: can I change the title of your question to "How to create the logical $|0_L \rangle$ state for the Steane's 7-qubit code"?

Comment: No problem :) you can change the title

Answer (score 2):

Here's a direct circuit to produce the logical $\bar{|0\rangle}$ state from  https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02524:

[image]

I'm not a qiskit expert, but in Cirq, I can check the superposition created by this:

```
import cirq

q = cirq.LineQubit.range(7)
state = cirq.Circuit(
    cirq.H(q[0]),
    cirq.H(q[1]),
    cirq.H(q[3]),
    cirq.CNOT(q[0], q[2]),
    cirq.CNOT(q[3], q[5]),
    cirq.CNOT(q[1], q[6]),
    cirq.CNOT(q[0], q[4]),
    cirq.CNOT(q[3], q[6]),
    cirq.CNOT(q[1], q[5]),
    cirq.CNOT(q[0], q[6]),
    cirq.CNOT(q[1], q[2]),
    cirq.CNOT(q[3], q[4]),
).final_state_vector(0, qubit_order=q)
print(cirq.dirac_notation(state))
```

results in

```
0.35|0000000⟩ + 0.35|0001111⟩ + 0.35|0110011⟩ + 0.35|0111100⟩ + 0.35|1010101⟩ + 0.35|1011010⟩ + 0.35|1100110⟩ + 0.35|1101001⟩
```

Answer (score -2):

Qubits are initialized at 0 so would you be wanting to flip certain qubits to 1?

I’m tempted to just apply x gates to obtain the necessary bits.

For example: |ψ⟩=...+|1010101⟩+...

from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(7)
qc.x([0, 2, 4, 6])

I hope I understood your question :)

Comment: I don't think that with this method you can obtain the superposition I need on the state $|\psi\rangle$, maybe you can prove that I'm wrong.

Comment: I guess that I have to use a combination of Hadamard and $\sigma_x$, but I don't know how to do that efficiently.