# Efficiently finding an explicit presentation for $N(S)/S$, for any stabilizer group $S$

Tags: stabilizer-code, pauli-group, stabilizer-state

Let $P_n$ denote the $n$-qubit Pauli group. This has presentation $P_n = \langle iI, X_1, \ldots, X_n, Z_1, \ldots, Z_n \rangle$. Suppose we have a stabilizer group $S = \langle s_1, \ldots, s_k \rangle \leq P_n$ minimally generated by $k$ elements. We know that $N(S)/S \cong P_{n-k}$, and hence there exists a presentation for $N(S)/S$ of the form $\langle \overline{\iota}, \overline{x_1}, \ldots, \overline{x_{n-k}}, \overline{z_1}, \ldots, \overline{z_{n-k}} \rangle$ whose generators obey the same commutativity relations as the generators of $P_{n-k} = \langle iI, X_1, \ldots, X_{n-k}, Z_1, \ldots, Z_{n-k} \rangle$.

My question is: is an efficient way of finding such a presentation for $N(S)/S$ known, for any given $S$?

I've read Gottesman's lecture notes (https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.2557) and a bit of his unpublished textbook, in which $N(S)/S$ is discussed and properties of it proved, but the key proofs I might otherwise use to derive an algorithm are existential rather than constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking to construct are the logical operators of the code. These operators are the representatives of each coset in $N(S)/S$.

There exists a process to do so, which was presented in Gottesman's thesis [1]. Please refer to step 1 and 2 of this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/28971/7939) which provides the generic process as well as a worked out example, for constructing the logical $X$ and $Z$ operators.

If you want, you can construct the logical $Y$ using the relation $Y=XZ$. Finally, the logical identity is just the all zero vector.

[1] D. Gottesman, Stabilizer Codes and Quantum Error Correction, arXiv:quant-ph/9705052.

Comment: Ahh nice, thanks!! I'll check out your 'stac' library :)

Comment: Very cool library! I have a question: I created a `stac.Code` from the generator matrix `[[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]`. i.e. I created the stabilizer group $S = \langle X_2 X_3, Z_2 Z_3 \rangle$. I expected this to have logical operators represented by $X_1$ and $Z_1$. Instead, when calling `.construct_logical_operators()` I got $X$ logicals `[[0 1 1 0 0 0]]` and $Z$ logicals `[[0 0 0 1 0 1]]`. i.e. I got the Paulis $X_2 X_3$ and $Z_1 Z_3$ respectively. These are not what I expected - e.g. $X_2 X_3$ is a stabilizer, so represents logical $I$. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Though it all works as expected if I create the group $S = \langle X_1 X_2, Z_1 Z_2 \rangle$ instead; it outputs $X$ logicals `[[0 0 1 0 0 0]]` and $Z$ logicals `[[0 0 0 0 0 1]]`, i.e. $X_3$ and $Z_3$.

Comment: @Yossarian This is a indeed a problem with the algorithm. You need to relabel your qubits to have at least one stabilizer targeting the 0th index (or 1st index if you are 1-indexing). I have also noticed some problems with the encoding circuits for n=2,3 codes. So please take stac with a grain of salt as it is currently in the dev phase.

Comment: No problem, consider a grain of salt taken. Really nice package idea, look forward to seeing more of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. You put the code in "standard" form. See Chapter 9 of

[https://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Information-Processing-Error-Correction/dp/0123854911](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123854911)

The process uses gaussian elimination and is similar to what you do for classical codes to get a standard (systematic) form. Qiskit or Stim might have this already built in by I'm not sure...